# Проблемы с кодировкой. LUA скрипт

Tags: lua

В чём может быть проблема?
Пишу скрипт на LUA в кодировке Windows-1251. Всё отлично работает, но после того, как я переоткрываю этот скрипт, русские символы меняются в нём на какие-то иероглифы..[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: LUA тут не при чём, проблема в настройках Notepad++.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , а есть возможность восстановления текущего кода.?
И у меня таки происходит не со всеми документами, не знаю, от чего это зависит

Comment: Используйте UTF-8 и при сохранении, и при открытии

Comment: Перекодировал документ в ANSI и всё восстановилось